# Geodesic curvature in hyperbolic geometry- Poincaré disk model

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

How is geodesic curvature defined with an ODE or geometric construction in the hyperbolic plane?

How do hyperbolic geodesics change when there is deviation from geodesy? How to construct or graph differently bent arcs in the hyperbolic plane, say in the Poincaré disk model?

Such definition is needed if a circumcircle needs to be drawn around three vertices of a triangle formed by three intersecting geodesics, or if a single in-circle has to drawn touching the three.

For geodesics passing through two points when concurrent on an arc of constant geodesic curvature at a third point.. should they subtend the same angle in some (yet to be defined) segment?

In Poincaré half plane model three geodesics touched by a non-geodesic constant geodesic curvature curve as a third touching circle is visualized as:

[image]

EDIT1:

To incorporate curvature into it, a geodesic needs to be a continuous curve to begin with. The following previous work is taken as background.

***Background***

[Including Outer Branch in Poincaré Disk model](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390096/poincar%C3%A9-hyperbolic-geodesics-in-half-plane-and-disc-models-including-outer-bran)

Consider disk model in the following attempt to derive hyperbolic geodesic curvature.

Valid for all eccentric circles product of line segments and arc differential

$$ \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} = \dfrac{1-T^2/r^2}{2a}; \dfrac{d\psi}{ds}= \dfrac{1+T^2/r^2}{2a} \tag 1 $$

For elliptic geodesics and integration gets Clairaut's constant as nearest distance to pole $C_1$.This follows Liouville's approach. Second Fundamental form using polar coordinates

$$ kg_E=\frac{d\psi}{ds} + \dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} +  =0 \rightarrow r \sin \psi = C_1 \tag2$$

and for hyperbolic geodesics I had introduced for all circles passing through origin with diameter $C_2$ and zero Power by integration as ***fundamentally defining hyperbolic geodesics***

$$\frac{d\psi}{ds} -\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r}  =0 \rightarrow r /\sin \psi = const. = C_2 \tag3$$

Subtract the first of Equn (1) from the second to obtain ***differential equation of  of the Poincaré disk model constant power T^2 and variable polar angle $ \sin ^{-1} (a/T) $***:

$$\frac{d\psi}{ds} -\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} - \frac{T^2/a}{r^2} =0 \tag4$$

At this stage in research with Poincaré disk model I introduce ***a constant extra term $k_{gH} $  as definition  for geodesic curvature***

$$\frac{d\psi}{ds} -\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} - \frac{T^2/a}{r^2} =k_{gH} \tag5$$

that is same as

$$\frac{\cos \psi\, d\psi}{dr} -\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} - \frac{T^2/a}{r^2} =k_{gH} \tag6$$

The ODE is integrated with initial conditions $ \psi=0, r=T $ obtaining solution

$$\dfrac{\sin \psi}{r} = \dfrac{1-T^2/r^2}{2a} + k_{gH} \,log\, (r/T) \tag7$$

By differentiation with respect to arc again

$$\dfrac{ d\psi}{ds} = \dfrac{1+T^2/r^2}{2a} + k_{gH} \,(1+log\, (r/T) ) \tag8$$

Note how Equns (1) are modified as Equations (7) and (8) due to geodesic curvature due to my definition.

Notice the case $ k_{gH}=0$ corresponds to *Poincaré disk model as a special case.*

Curves with two geodesic curvature numerical values are given below:

[image: Poincaré Half Plane]

The results show how ***precession and distortion***  are introduced under the influence of $\kappa_{gH} $ brought into definition here.

EDIT2:
I request for any references providing geometric /differential geometric definitions in either of two Poincaré models (half plane or disk) or the Klein-Beltrami model. I request you also for  critical appraisal of my basic approach above. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.